# Python dynamic from?

Tags: python, import

I was wondering if there exists a dynamic form of from in Python. Specifically because I want to use `from 'project' import h`, where project is a variable and h is a particular class instantiation. I know there's modulelib's `import_module()`, so I was wondering if there was something like that for `from`. Or would I just have to use `import_module()` and then call h from that?

Comment: Yes, you would have to use `import_module` and then get `h` from the resulting module object.

Answer (score -1):

Check `__import__`:

[https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#**import**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__)

```
tmp = __import__('project', globals(), locals(), ['h'])
h = tmp.h
```

should be what you're looking for.

Which, looking at it, is not that much better than the `import_module` based solution...

Comment: You shouldn't use `__import__` directly unless you handle namespace packages and other edge cases yourself.